# How to Send an HTML and CSS Stylized Email Through PHP From Server

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to create an "HTML Mail" on my server. I already Google this an there are lots of tutorial about designing and styleing of HTML Mails like [This One](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-html-emails--net-17200) but none of them explain how to hire PHP to send this HTML format!?
I already tried this

```
<?php
$msg ="";
$msg.= '<div style="background:red;">Please Accept Format!</div>';
 mail("test@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

but in GMail inbox I am getting

```
> <div style="background:red;">Please Accept Format!</div>
```

Can you please let me know how I can use PHP to send HTML and CSS formatted Mails?

Thanks

Comment: You need to send an HTML formatted email, which is possible with `mail()` but fiddly. Make life easier and use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending html email, you must specify that in the headers

```
<?php
$msg ="";
$msg.= '<div style="background:red;">Please Accept Format!</div>';
 mail("test@gmail.com", "My subject", $msg, "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8");
?>
```

Also there are various libraries which can make your life easier as well. One of the easier ones to install and use is PEAR Mail, which you can ready about @ http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

I personally use swiftmailer with many projects. What you use is purely up to you, but using such classes simplifies various other tasks you will do with email in due time.

Comment: Thanks skrilled , this is working! I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer but thanks